# Why is this Javascript code not adding to input?

Tags: javascript, html, function, user-input, addition

I'm taking user input and using Javascript to add 5 to the number provided. Javascript puts number together (1 becomes 15 and not 6). It also is opening it in a new page; I want it in its own paragraph beneath it. Am I over complicating this?

I created a function to call to take user input, check if number is between 0 and 10, and if yes add 5 to it. If it is not, then an error message would appear to say input a number between 0 and 10. Code is down below, and here is the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/HanSolo0001/Back-To-Basics) I made for it as well.

```js
// This code checks if input is between 0 and 10. If it is code will run (in this case addition), if not error message occurs. 
function number() {
    var myNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value;
    if (myNumber >= 0 || myNumber <= 10) {
        var result = myNumber + 5;
        document.write(result).innerHTML;
    } else {
        document.write("Please input a number between 0 and 10.");
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
        <span>Enter a number between 0 and 10.</span><br>
        <textarea id="inputNumber" label="Enter a number between 0 and 10."></textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="numberResult" onclick="number()">Click here to run addition Javascript!</button>
        <p id="myResult"></p>
    </section>
```

So the Javascript is supposed to take the user input (number between 0 and 10) and add it to 5. What's happening is the number is just tagged onto the 5 and opened up in a new page when button is clicked to show result. i.e. 1 becomes 15 and not 6 (1 + 5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to convert string to integer first

```
var result = Number(myNumber) + 5;
```

then assign value to the p tag with id myresult

```
document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = result;
```